# spymemcached get() or asyncget()?

Tags: spymemcached

In a multi threaded application like in servlets if we want to use a single spymemcached object, should I use the get() method or the asyncget() method to get values from cache ?

I'm a little unsure whether I've interpreted the spymemcached documentation correctly - so this question.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the `asyncGet` and a `get` is that in asyncGet, you are not waiting for the operation to complete and getting back a return value straight after the call. You simply fire and forget. That said, you need to periodically check the Future object handle that is given to you for the return value.

In a `get`, you wait for the operation to complete as long as it takes, the Java thread waits for the call to Memcached to complete and return, even if it happens that there is a server error in Memcached that kicks in the re-try logic, you need to wait for this to complete too.

Therefore, the difference between an `asyncGet` and `get` is not with one being able to handle more of such requests than the other, or that `get` is concurrent while `asyncGet` isn't.